# Possible to designate which Mac / iDevice pops up PIN for software updates

Tags: macos, icloud, location-services

Can I set iCloud to popup a single sysadmin's Mac when an iCloud-enabled device performs a software update?  Or disable that popup?

My office has multiple Macs and iOS devices, loaded with the same iCloud login so that we can run Find My Mac / iPhone.  However, that means that when I run software updates like the MacOS 10.13 update, that random Macs loaded with the same iCloud account will present a popup.  If I do it during the workday, then the users are interrupted, so I have to do the maintenance at night.  I have several of the Macs / iDevices at my desk, so I will get one of the popups and be able to enter the temporary PIN.

If Find My Mac can be enabled without the software update popup on other machines, that's a good solution too.

Comment: Why are multiple users connected to the same iCloud account? Are you using an MDM solution?

Comment: Management wanted Track My Mac to work from his browser.  It's not worth investing money or significant time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANY and ALL devices and accounts logged into the iCloud account may or may not pop up prompts when the iCloud 2-Factor Authentication popup is requested.  iOS 9 and up, Mac OS 10.9 and up.

HOWEVER, it only interrupts a user if currently logged into a Mac with the current Mac user logged into the iCloud account.

THEREFORE, the resolution for my purposes is to create a Mac account specific for sysadmins, which was already on most of the Macs, and log into the iCloud account on that Mac account.  Log out of the iCloud account on the user-specific Mac accounts.  Later, the 2FA popups don't pop on the regular users.  It will popup while logged into the sysadmins.